# angularjs ng-include pass value from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to include subpages to my main page..

I'm using `ng-include`.. when I tried to put using this `ng-include="'samplePage.php'"` it works... but what I want is to assign the value of `ng-include` in the controller...

**here's my hmtl code**

```
<div id="navbar-override" class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "navbar-header">
                <a href = "index.html" class = "navbar-brand">
                    Sample App
                </a>
                <button id="navbar-btn-override" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-repeat="link in Links"  ng-class="{'active': selectedItem === link}">
                    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" ng-click="Link(this)">{{ link }}</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" ng-include="pages">
          <!--subpages will append here-->
    </div>
```

**my controller.js**

```
indexApp.controller('indexCtrl', ['$window','$scope', '$http', function($window, $scope, $http) {

$scope.pages = "./pages/customer.php";

}]);
```

if you ask me why I do this.. because I'm planing to use `ng-include` dynamically......

I'm still new to angularjs so bear with me...
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work,

Your HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
     <option value="">(blank)</option>
    </select>
    url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-include src="template.url" onload='myFunction()'></div>
  </div>

<!-- template1.php-->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="./pages/template1.php">
  Content of template1.php
</script>

<!-- template2.php-->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="./pages/template2.php">
    <p ng-class="color">Content of template2.php</p>
</script>
```

Controller :

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.templates = [{
        name: 'template1.php',
        url: './pages/template1.php'},
    {
        name: 'template2.php',
        url: './pages/template2.php'}];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MfHa6/1517/

Comment: @SamTengWong i had updated my answer with example , can you check it this is helpful.?

Comment: sorry my mistake... it's now working.... the actual name of my file is `customers.php`... it took me an hour to notice... my bad.. but thanks for helping...